# JSP tld not working migrating from Weblogic to Tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, weblogic

I'm migrating a Java application with lots of JSPs from Weblogic to Tomcat.

I have a `.tld` file with

```
<tag>
    <name>select</name>
    <tagclass>path.to.java.class</tagclass>
    <bodycontent>empty</bodycontent>
    <attribute>
         <name>class</name>
         <required>false</required>
         <rtexprvalue>false</rtexprvalue>
    </attribute>
</tag>
```

The setter in the Java class is

```
public void setClass()...
```

But this is not working. I am getting the below error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: myFile.jsp (line: 458, column: 13) Unable to find setter method for attribute: class
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:443)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:149)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.evaluateAttribute(Generator.java:2868)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.generateSetters(Generator.java:3092)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.generateCustomStart(Generator.java:2262)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1757)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1539)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2428)
```

But when I change everything from 'class' to 'blass' and setClass() to setBlass() everything works fine.

What is the issue here? Why is it working on Weblogic but not Tomcat?

Comment: Probably defensive programming in Jasper to avoid a clash with the reserved word `class` and Weblogic is not using Jasper.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am getting the same problem.

Comment: @johannes jander I get the message "org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /abc.jsp (line: 384, column: 3) The TLD for the class com.abc.tags.ActionTag specifies an invalid body-content (JSP) for a SimpleTag."

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue under *Weblogic => Tomcat 8.5.X* migration - because of using **class** word the JSP generation was failing. After changing it to something different it started working.